# 2D array horizontal reflection in c

Tags: c

For the reflection code I need to reflect a picture vertically (most left go to most right). But this code below does not change a thing. (I also tried to give up on pointers and use the arrays itself in swap function but did not change a thing either.)

REFLECT:

```
void swap(RGBTRIPLE* p, RGBTRIPLE* q)
{
    RGBTRIPLE* temp;
    temp = p;
    p = q;
    q = temp;
}


    // Reflect image horizontally
    void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width/2; j++)
            {
                swap(&image[i][j],&image[i][width-1-j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your swap function should change to:

```
void swap(RGBTRIPLE* p, RGBTRIPLE* q)
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp; // use a value temp instead of pointer temp
    temp = *p; // you should swap the value that pointer points to.
    *p = *q;
    *q = temp;
}
```

If you want to swap the pointers themselves, the function will be as below:

```
void swap(RGBTRIPLE** p, RGBTRIPLE** q)
{
    RGBTRIPLE* temp;
    temp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now I see what a silly mistake I made. I was just changing the pointer's addresses but I need to change the values of them. @Hitoriki